# nVidia drivers block Virtualbox (/dev/vboxdrv does not exist)

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, 17.10, linux-headers

After installing nvidia-387 drivers, I can't seem to run virtualbox anymore.

`VBoxManage --version` output:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.1.30_Ubuntur118389
```

Trying to install virtualbox-dkms:

```
virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version (5.1.30-dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Linux headers:

```
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.13.0.21.22).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

By purging nvidia drivers I can run virtualbox without any problems but the obvious downside is that this way I cannot enjoy the blessing of my graphics card.

Do you have any clever solutions to this?
I've noticed people mentioning disabling the secure boot but it's already disabled and I believe the problem is within the drivers given the fact that virtualbox runs perfectly when I uninstall them.

Comment: It seems to be a correlation but certainly not causation. I've been using Virtualbox with Nvidia drivers for years in many different machines without any issue.

Comment: It's probably related to DKMS.
@MichaelBay Do you use Ubuntu 17.10. and latest virtualbox?

Comment: I've been using it for more than a decade with a variety of Ubuntu releases, Virtualbox versions and Nvidia drivers versions and yes, including the current 17.10.